# Update By Query: Inline script ctx with multiple statements fail if one or more items don't match?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using below inline script with update by query to update `approved=true` in elastic and the timestamp `lastModifiedDate`.

```
POST /limp-access/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "_id": [
                "asdasfasf-laHg5qeld",
                "asdfadfdfdsf-asdasd"
             ]
        }
    },
    "script":{
    "source": "ctx._source.approved = true; ctx._source.fields.lastModifiedDate = ['2019-05-21T06:16:05.133Z'];"
  }
}
```

The problem is that some documents do not have this field `lastModifiedDate` at all. So whenever it encounters such doc, it fails with null pointer expression. Is there a way to ignore such docs and update the one's where it is found?

EDIT: Posting the error that I get below:

> {   "error": {
>       "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "type": "script_exception",
>           "reason": "runtime error",
>           "script_stack": [
>             "ctx._source.fields.lastModifiedDate = ['2019-05-21T06:16:05.133Z'];",
>             "                  ^---- HERE"
>           ],
>           "script": "ctx._source.approved = true; ctx._source.fields.lastModifiedDate = ['2019-05-21T06:16:05.133Z'];",
>           "lang": "painless"
>         }
>       ],
>       "type": "script_exception",
>       "reason": "runtime error",
>       "script_stack": [
>         "ctx._source.fields.lastModifiedDate = ['2019-05-21T06:16:05.133Z'];",
>         "                  ^---- HERE"
>       ],
>       "script": "ctx._source.approved = true; ctx._source.fields.lastModifiedDate = ['2019-05-21T06:16:05.133Z'];",
>       "lang": "painless",
>       "caused_by": {
>         "type": "null_pointer_exception",
>         "reason": null
>       }   },   "status": 500 }

The expectation is that if one the IDs do not have the field `fields`, I want it to be ignored and the script to update the rest of the documents where the field `fields` is found. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean that some documents don't have the field named `fields`. Can you show the error you get?

Comment: @Val Yes, some documents do not have this field. I have updated the error in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then simply update your script like this:

```
"source": "ctx._source.approved = true; if (ctx._source.fields != null) { ctx._source.fields.lastModifiedDate = ['2019-05-21T06:16:05.133Z'];}"
```

Comment: I am a newbie elastic user and was not aware of `if` statements in elastic. Your solution seems to be perfect for the problem in question.